Using Polite with unnamed arguments
I want to scrape some data from IMDB and the URL structure is as following https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0903747/episodes/. I want to bow and the scrape some different codes. How can I achieve this using map and scrape?
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(polite)

session <- bow("https://www.imdb.com/title/")
results <- map(c("tt903747", "tt5491994"),~scrape(session, query = list(.x, "episodes")))


query needs a named list, e.g., list(episode = 3, season = 4) Perhaps you've been misled on what is scrape does--- it builds and queries a URL for you, e.g.,  titleID = 1234 => scrape(.x, query = ... would become www.url.com/?title=1234/ What you need for this site is a URL set up is like this bow(paste0("https://www.imdb.com/title/", .x, "/episodes/")) (BTW: The first title doesn't exist; you're missing a number, perhaps "tt0903747" instead?).

@Kat, in this case, do I need to bow for every single URL then?

If you decide to use polite, yes. However, if your end goal is querying IMDB, this may not be the best tool for the job. Their robots appears to be written in such a way that it seems to thwart that type of scraping (along with the way their URLs are built. (What I mean, regarding robots are lines like "/search/name-text" indicating that that essentially the use of scrape() won't be particularly useful here.
